# clearing the console and viewing dataframes in rodeo

Tags: python, pandas, rodeo

I am using rodeo with jupyter however the keyboard shortcuts for switching to and clearing terminal are not working, and either is the ability to view and sort pandas dataframes by clicking on them in the top right panel.

http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rodeo are you using?  (You *should* be able to tell by clicking Rodeo > About Rodeo).

The Rodeo team has been working on a major re-write from version 1.3, the current downloadable version on yhat's website.  I recommend upgrading to their latest release, [version 1.4.9](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo) downloadable from github.

Can't speak for other versions, but in 1.4.9 you can clear the console using ctrl+l and you can switch between the editor and the console using cmd+1 and cmd+2.

Also, keep checking for updated versions on github as they are coming fast! Oh, and whenever I reached out to the Rodeo team via github with a reasonable request they were quick to implement it.